# Configure crontab to execute Laravel Task Scheduling

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, cron, scheduled-tasks

I set this on my cron file

```
*    *    *    *    *    php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

I have this in my Kernel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Carbon;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        \App\Console\Commands\Inspire::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $now = Carbon\Carbon::now('America/New_York');
        $dt = Carbon\Carbon::parse($now);
        $time_start = $dt->toTimeString();
        $dt = str_replace('-','_',$dt);
        $dt = str_replace(' ','_',$dt);
        $dt = str_replace('/',':',$dt);
        $schedule->exec('curl '.env('APP_URL').'fbwifi/acl_update')->everyMinute()
            ->sendOutputTo(public_path().'/tasks/log_'.$dt.'.txt');
    }
}
```

---

If I manually run

```
php artisan schedule:run
```

I got

```
Running scheduled command: curl http://localhost:8888/fbwifi/acl_update > '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/site/portal/public/tasks/log_2016_10_21_14:01:33.txt' 2>&1 &
```

and I see the file to be the log file generated perfectly fine.

---

Then, I wait another 5 mins, I don't see anything else. I am supposed to get five more logs generated.

Did I do anything wrong ? How do I check this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of having `php artisan schedule:run` in cron, create a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

/full/path/to/php /full/path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /tmp/debug.log 2>&1
```

In your crontab, place the full path to this shell script.

Your crontab runs every minute.  If you want to it every 5 minutes, use this:

```
*/5 * * * * /home/user/myshellscript.sh
```

You can then examine `/tmp/debug.log` for errors.

If you do not want a bash scipt, try this in crontab:

```
*/5 * * * * /full/path/to/php /full/path/to/artisan "schedule:run" >> /tmp/debug.log 2>&1
```

Comment: If I want to keep what I have without to create a bash file, what should be my cron tab command ?

Comment: I usually do this `php artisan schedule:run` and it works, how do I know the full path of my php/artisan ?

Comment: from the shell type: `which php` and maybe `find /usr -type f -name artisan` (not sure)

Comment: I used the one that come with MAMP.

Comment: U think I can use this one too `/usr/local/php5/bin/php` ?

Comment: @ihue: sure, try it!